# GNU Make: wildcards in static pattern rules

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Can wildcards be used in the static pattern rule context in GNU make? For example:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/$(DEPENDENCIES) : */%.d : $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c
      ...
```

Comment: See [wildcard](http://theory.uwinnipeg.ca/localfiles/infofiles/make/make_25.html) function

Comment: Not like that, no. The asterisk doesn't work. (And neither does the target name, if `DEPENDENCIES` is what I think it is.) But you can probably get the effect you're trying for. Can you tell us more about the makefile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave the `$(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c` off the static pattern rule, and enter the dependencies on a separate line. Maybe:

```
# Tell make "build/f.d: source/f.c" for each source file
$(foreach _,${srcs},$(eval ${BUILD_DIR}/$(notdir $_): $_))

${BUILD_DIR}/${DEPENDENCIES}: ${BUILD_DIR}/%.d:
    ...
```

This answers the question, though I share @Beta's opinion that this is not what you want.